# How can I access a Fedora 18 partition on Windows? ext2explorer doesn't work

Tags: windows, fedora

I had Fedora 17 and [ext2explore 2.2.71](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/) worked as advertised. Since I installed Fedora 18, it no longer works. I already reinstall the program, but the program can't detect the partition.
What alternatives do I have? ext2explore was the most recent program I could find

Comment: So you made sure, that it your file system is still in a supported (=ext2/ext3/ext4/lvm) partition format?

Comment: I did, it's ext4 like in Fedora 17.

Comment: Alright. :) You might want to try other products that claim to be able to mount ext4, like http://www.ext2fsd.com, http://ext2read.blogspot.com or http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext4tc.

Comment: Just tried **all** those without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gotcha!

Using [Disk Internals Linux Reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) I can read my files again. It's a bit clunky, but it's enough to copy a file or two sometimes, I don't need more.

The "problem" is that Fedora 18 uses LVM by default, so ext2explore couldn't find the drive.